# Proper way to include stylesheet for panels

Tags: plugin-development, css

What is the proper way to include a stylesheet with my options panels in wp-admin for a given plugin or theme. In other words -- the stylesheet that styles the panels.

I mean, in my panel template code, I'm doing something like...

```
<style type="text/css">
@import url("../wp-content/plugins/myplugin/panels/style.css");
</style>
```

...but suspect that this won't work on some installs of WordPress because of paths and so on, and might not work in the future of WP gets a wild hair and wants to rename wp-content with something else.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style
also follow examples on those page.

Comment: @Sisir please post *answers* as **answers**, rather than as **comments**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *best practice* method of enqueueing admin stylesheets is to [**hook into your appearance page's specific hook**](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/6/), using the `admin_print_styles-{hook}`, where `{hook}` = `{admin_page}-{menu_slug}`.

I'll assume:

1. This is a Theme
2. You are properly using an *appearance* page, via `add_appearance_page()`
3. Your `$menu_slug` is `wpse48416-settings`

The hook, then, is: `admin_print_styles-appearance_page_wpse48416-settings`:

```
<?php
function wpse48416_admin_style(){
        wp_register_style( 'wpse48416_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/admin.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse48416_admin_css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-appearance_page_wpse48416-settings', 'wpse48416_admin_style' );
?>
```

For a Plugin, you simply need to use the correct `{page}` string, depending on which admin menu function you use to register your settings page, e.g. `settings_page` for `add_settings_page()`.

Comment: What do I do if I'm using add_menu_page() and add_submenu_page() to add my admin panels?

Comment: "*What do I do if I'm using add_menu_page() and add_submenu_page() to add my admin panels*" - well, the *best practice* first step would be to switch to `add_theme_page()` or `add_settings_page()`. (*grin*). But, I think, for `add_menu_page()` or `add_submenu_page()`, you'd use `admin_page` instead of `appearance_page`.

Comment: I found that they have some fantastic examples at the bottom of these pages to solve my problem, and I have it working! Yay! Go to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/, then search "wp_enqueue_script" and "wp_enqueue_style".

Comment: BTW, you said this was the best practice, but is it still the best practice? Note I just discovered this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts

Comment: Yes, I'm positive that [it's best practice to use an appropriate sub-menu, rather than a top-level menu, for a Theme/Plugin admin pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus#Determining_Location_for_New_Menus).

Comment: I my case, I have at least 4 forms for my plugin, and one of those forms is a list page to select from 50 items. So, I chose a top-level menu. Besides, I think it's confusing in WordPress when you install a plugin named "X" and then its menu is called "Links", and you don't know this and go looking under Settings, only to be confused. WordPress must fix this in the future.

Comment: You know that you can create tabs for your settings page, right? Also: you can put a settings page link in the plugin_meta_row on the Dashboard -> Plugins page, so that users don't have to hunt for your settings page. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3100/discussion-between-volomike-and-chip-bennett)

Answer (score 1):

```
function load_myplugin_wp_admin_style(){
        wp_register_style( 'myplugin_wp_admin_css', plugins_url( '/myplugin/panels/style.css' ), false, '1.0.0' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'myplugin_wp_admin_css' );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_myplugin_wp_admin_style');
```

Comment: While this method *works*, it will print your custom stylesheet on **every admin page**. At *best*, it represents bloat; at *worst*, it will cause style breakage for core and/or other Plugins.